# Using tail bounds when some variables are statistically dependent

Tags: probability, distribution-tails

If $X$ is a binomial random variable with parameters $n$ and $p$, then by known [tail bounds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Tail_Bounds):

$$ \Pr[X\leq k] \leq \exp\left(-2 \frac{(np-k)^2}{n}\right),\!$$

and if there are $m$ such i.i.d. random variables, $X_1,\dots,X_m$, then the probability that **at least one** variable is less than $k$ is:

$$ \Pr[X_1\leq k \cup \dots \cup X_m\leq k] \leq m\cdot\exp\left(-2 \frac{(np-k)^2}{n}\right),\!$$
by the union bound.

What happens if the variables $X_1,\dots,X_m$ are statistically dependent? Is the second inequality still true?

Comment: Just curious: When they are i.i.d., should not the RHS to be raised by power $m$ to get the bound as tight as the first one? This union bound will be even looser than the first one. If I have understood correctly, you are interesting in the probability of intersection of all event. In the extreme case, if $X_1 = X_2 = \ldots = X_m$, then you can only refer to the first bound obtained. And whenever it satisfy the first bound, it also satisfy the second bound you posted here.

Comment: @BGM I made a mistake - I meant to ask about the union of the events (the event of being less than $k$ is a "bad" event).

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boole%27s_inequality It does not require they are independent event. Bonferroni inequalities will gives a tighter bound.